# How Do you Reference Coldfusion Instances in Clustered Server Environment

Tags: coldfusion, instance

If there are multiple Coldfusion instances on a server, in a clustered server environment, how do you reference it? For instance, if we had multiple servers and we wanted to find out which server we were hitting with a web call we could use #CGI.Server_Name# which would gives the IP address of the server we were hitting. What I'm asking is how we could tell which instance of Coldfusion we're on, on a given server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods I've used are to either include an HTTP header in the response, or an HTML comment that outputs the name of the server so you can view it with debugging tools.

No, on to your specific question about the **instance**, you haven't said what ever of CF engine you're using, so I can't promise this code will work on all versions, but this is what I have used in the past on JRun-based versions of Adobe ColdFusion:

```
instanceName = createObject("java", "jrunx.kernel.JRun").getServerName();
```

This shuold work on the newer, Tomcat-based versions of CF (10+)

```
instanceName = createobject("component","CFIDE.adminapi.runtime").getinstancename();
```

This is what I have used on Railo/Lucee

```
instanceName = getRailoId().server.id;
instanceName = getLuceeId().server.id;
```

To output as a comment, add something like this to the top of your layout.  Note, this can ONLY be used on responses returning HTML, not JS for instance.

```
<!-- CF Instance: #instanceName# -->
```

Or add an HTTP header like so:

```
<cfheader name="CF-Instance" value="#instanceName#">
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. We are on CF10.  The first line of code for getServerName gives me an error.  The second line of code works. It gives me "cfusion".  I'm not sure if that's all I would need. Are there any other functions that could provide me more info? Also, could you provide an example of the HTTP header response or HTML comment that you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, "cfusion" sounds like the default instance name.  If you have done a multi-instance installation of ColdFusion, you should be able to name the instances as you create them.  This assumes they are running in the same JVM.  I updated the answer to show adding an HTML comment and HTTP header.